# 404 page redirect issue for all subpages?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using drupal7 404 page redirect to my custom page using htaccess.

I have to handle 404 error for all subpages. Example : www.example.com/one/two/(INVALID_URI) to my custompage.

I used this in .htacces Errordocument 404 /custom404.php this working only for www.example.com/(INVALID_URI). i need the rule for above example.

How to fix this redirect issue?

Comment: I suggest posting your full .htaccess as part of your question, formatting the code appropriately. See:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: and specify which method you use to parse php, because the solution or way to do it surely depends on it.